# Transfer Norton Identity Safe Data To Bitdefender Wallet?

Tags: import, password-management, bitdefender, norton-360

Having had all my passwords in Norton Identity Safe, I exported them as a .csv form to import them into Bitdefender Wallet.

After having uninstalled Norton 360, and installed Bitdefender, I saw that it could not import .csv files, only db files.

I can not do the process of inserting my passwords one by one into Bitdefender Wallet as there way too many. Does anyone know how I can get them in from the .csv file?